# c# - write 10 random lines from a file (without duplicates) into each of 15 files

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, random, file-io

so I have been trying to make a function that

1. iterates through each file in a folder of 26 files,
2. takes 10 random lines from a file of 20 lines,
3. checks if the currently chosen line is already in the current file, if it is then try choosing again,
4. writes the 10 random lines into each file.

This is what I have got so far. But I don't know why it's always out of bounds. I have tried putting the lines from file into another array via loop but this doesn't help either. Does anyone see what's wrong?

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"randomLines.txt");
assignLines(lines);
static void assignLines(string[] listOfLines)
        { 
            Random rnd = new Random();

            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"files", @"*.txt"))
            {
                string[] assignedLines = new string[] { };
                int j = 1;
                int i = 0;
                StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(file);
                while (i < 5)
                //for (int i = 0; i < File.ReadAllLines(file).Length + 1; i++)
                {

                    int chosen = rnd.Next(0, listOfLines.Length - 1);

                    if (assignedLines.Contains(listOfLines[chosen]))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        assignedLines[i] = listOfLines[chosen];
                        wr.WriteLine(j + ". " + listOfLines[chosen] + ".");
                        j++;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                wr.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: assigned lines is a 0 length array `new string[] { };` I think you likely had in mind to use it as a List<string> or if not it would make life easier for you at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting a random line and each time looping trough lines to see if it is duplicate or not, you can order your lines randomly and then take 10 of them:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"randomLines.txt")
                 .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
                 Take(10)
                 .ToArray();
```

If as you mentioned in the comments, also your lines could contain duplicates, then remove duplicates before order:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"randomLines.txt")
                 .Distinct()     //this line will remove duplicates
                 .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
                 Take(10)
                 .ToArray();
```

Now you can loop thought files and write these 10 lines.

Comment: the problem with your solution is that they will duplicate and there is no checking for duplicates

Comment: So there are duplicates in those 20 lines itself? can those 20 lines contain duplicates?

Comment: these 20 lines have no duplicates

Comment: this works great thanks just had to change `.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())` to `.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next(0, listOfLines.Length -1))` for it to work

Comment: @Typhoon glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you're asking this should in theory work for you

```
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("FILE");
    
                // This will filter the array so that items which only appear once in 'lines' will be returned.
                // Once because lines will also contain the current item we are checking against.
                //Take 10 just returns the first 10 from that list
    string[] linesThatOnlyApprearOnce = lines.Where(x => lines.Count(y => x == y) == 1).Take(10).ToArray();
```